# How many $5$-digit numbers can be formed from the integers $1, 2, \ldots, 9$ if no digit can appear more than twice?

Tags: combinatorics

> How many $5$-digit numbers can be formed from
> the integers $1, 2, \ldots, 9$ if no digit can appear more
> than twice? (For instance, $41434$ is not allowed.)

Here is my attempt:
There are basically 3 scenarios:

1. No digits repeat: $9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5$
2. One pair of same digit: $9 \cdot \binom{5}{2} \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6$
3. Two different pairs: $9 \cdot \binom{5}{2} \cdot 8 \cdot \binom{3}{2} \cdot 7$

I'm trying to match a textbook answer and I match the first two but not the third - I'm high by a factor of 2. Not sure what's wrong.

Comment: In 3. you count every combination of two pairs twice. It should be $\binom92\binom52\binom32\times7$.

Comment: OK, thanks. But I'm still not sure I get it.  Here is my logic for 3.) : for the first pair there are 9 digits and 2 slots out of 5 to fill; for the second pair 8 digits remain to fill 2 slots out of 3; and then finally 7 digits remaining for 1 slot.

Comment: If for the first pair you choose 11 and for the second 22 then there are $\binom52\binom32\times7$ possibilities. However if for the first pair you choose 22 and for the second 11 then you *recount* these possibilities.

Comment: Explaining your reasoning in the question would help readers detect any errors you may have made.

Answer (score 1):

There are $\binom52\binom32\times7$ numbers of that sort that contain twice a $1$ and twice a $2$.

I preassume that is clear to you.

Next to that there are $\binom92$ ways to choose these two numbers $1$ and $2$.

In your answer on $3$ you actually go for $9\times8$ ways, so land in double counting.

Comment: Yes, now I see why you are correct!  And clear that I'm wrong.  I'm still having trouble seeing the flaw in my logic, but that's for me to kick in my head for a while.  Thanks again!

Comment: To sharp your intuition you could work out a simpler example. E.g. how many $4$ digit numbers (containing only the digits from set $\{1,2\}$) are there that contain two distinct pairs? If this answer is suitable for you then you can accept it.

Comment: Yes, that helped.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is your error:**  Suppose the number you are forming is $12321$.  Your method counts this number in two ways:

- You first choose $1$ as a repeated number as one of your nine choices, you place it in positions $1$ and $5$ when you choose two of the five positions for the ones, then you choose $2$ as your other repeated number using one of your eight choices, then you place it in positions $2$ and $4$ when you choose two of the remaining three positions for the twos, and then you choose $3$ as the remaining digit as one of your seven choices for the singleton and place the $3$ in the third position.
- You first choose $2$ as a repeated number as one of your nine choices, you place it in positions $2$ and $4$ when you choose two of the five positions for the ones, then you choose $1$ as your other repeated number using one of your eight choices, then you place it in positions $1$ and $5$ when you choose two of the remaining three positions for the twos, and then you choose $3$ as the remaining digit as one of your seven choices for the singleton and place the $3$ in the third position.

However, these two sequences of choices yield the same number.  You have counted every five-digit number in which you have two digits which appear twice and one digit which appears once twice since there are two orders in which you could construct the same number.  Therefore, you need to divide your answer for that case by $2$.

Note that $$\binom{9}{2} = \frac{9!}{7!2!} = \frac{9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7!}{7! \cdot 2 \cdot 1} = \frac{9 \cdot 8}{2}$$

**How to correct your error:**  Choose which two of the nine digits will appear twice.  Choose two of the five positions for the smaller of the selected  digits.  Choose two of the remaining three positions for the larger of the selected digits.  Choose one of the remaining seven digits to fill the remaining position.
$$\binom{9}{2}\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{2}\binom{7}{1}$$

Comment: That is a nice explanation. Thanks!